# Browser gets two different SSL certificates instead of one (IE only)

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, internet-explorer, sni

It seems the problem appears only for IE11 (Win) users, for other OS and browsers HTTPS connection works fine.

1. IE11 firstly gets outdated SSL certificate warning
2. You ignore warning, proceed anyway
3. After you proceed IE shows different certificate with different serial number and it is valid, no warnings anymore

Any suggestions?

Server: nginx, SNI enabled - several domains on same ip (listed in cert SANS field).

SOLUTION: IE was taking second (outdated one) certificate from other domain which was outdated. Searching certificate body on all servers we have helped to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the outdated certificate is not installed on the server or present in any other way. It seems like this could be the problem.